# default search paths for CMake include() vs. find_package()

Tags: cmake

I have VTK6 installed on my Debian machine and it places all its CMake files under

```
$ ls /usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/
[...]
VTKConfig.cmake
vtkModuleAPI.cmake
[...]
```

When I do

```
find_package(VTK)
```

in another project, it all works out fine. However,

```
include(vtkModuleAPI)
```

yields the error

```
include could not find load file:

  vtkModuleAPI
```

I had always been under the impression that `find_package()` and `include` share the same search paths, specifically `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. Apparently that's not correct.

Note that

```
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3")
include(vtkModuleAPI)
```

does work.

Also note that I'm using CMake 3.5, so there no longer is a `FindVTK.cmake` [as it used to be](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindVTK.html).

What are the default search paths for `find_package()` and `include()`? Why is `vtkModuleAPI.cmake` not found?

Answer (score 7):

There are **two modes** of [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html), which have many differences:

1. **Module mode** tries to locate `FindXXX.cmake` file. The file is searched under directories listed in *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* plus under directory where CMake is installed.
2. **Config mode** tries to locate `XXXConfig.cmake` file. The file is searched under directories listed in *CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH* and some other, system-specific variables. (Full algorithm see in the documentation, linked at the beginning of the post).

Command [include](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/include.html) searches modules only under directories in *CMAKE_MODULE_PATH* and special CMake module directory.

As you can see, command `include` and command `find_package` in *module mode* uses similar search paths. But in your case, `VTKConfig.cmake` can be searched only in *config mode* of `find_package`, which uses *completely different search algorithm*.

---

In case of VTK, CMake has shipped `FindVTK.cmake` file, which is used when you call `find_package(VTK)`. But inside, this script uses `find_package(VTK QUIET NO_MODULE)`.

If this call locates file `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKConfig.cmake`, it executes this script, and the script includes `vtkModuleAPI.cmake` one.

If your `VTKConfig.cmake` is not located by CMake, you may help it by setting *VTK_DIR* variable to `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/`.

[Starting with CMake-3.1, `FindVTK.cmake` is no longer shipped with CMake, so `find_package(VTK)` immediately tries to locate `VTKConfig.cmake`].

---

In any case, modules in directory `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/` **shouldn't be included directly**: this directory is **private** for VTK.

Comment: CMake no longer provides `FindVTK.cmake`; see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindVTK.html.

Comment: Thanks for info, I have added notion about that into the post.

Comment: I think the second part of the post can be condensed to its last sentence. Would be great to have that backed up, too. The include problem comes from ParaView, btw (https://github.com/Kitware/ParaView/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L576). -- The company that created VTK _and_ CMake. (That doesn't mean they're always using it correctly of course.)

Comment: I have decided to just emphasize the last sentence. As for ParaView, its script actually plays dirty with VTK (read: uses VTK internals). Before including `vtkModuleAPI` module, it appends *VTK_MODULES_DIR* to the search path, and value of that variable is another internal of VTK.

Answer (score 1):

`find_package(VTK)` uses `FindVTK.cmake` (in it's *module mode*, [c.f. docu on `find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html)), which is shipped by CMake and (in your case) should be located in `/usr/share/cmake/Modules`.

After adding `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3` to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, `find_package(VTK)` will still use the same `FindVTK.cmake` module.

In case you want to use another `FindVTK.cmake` module, prepend the path to that `FindVTK.cmake` module to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

`include()` will not use a *find module* and only *sees* files located in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`.

Comment: "find_package(VTK) uses FindVTK.cmake" – I don't think that's true. I tested it and it uses `/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKConfig.cmake`. CMake no longer provides a `FindVTK.cmake`, see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindVTK.html.