# Receiving error "include could not find load file" for cmake

Tags: ios, swift, windows, cmake

Setting up swift-corelibs-xctest for Swift - Windows 10.  When file CMakeLists.txt  is called find_package is ran to look for FoundationConfig.cmake file

```
if(NOT CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL Darwin)
  find_package(dispatch CONFIG REQUIRED)
  find_package(Foundation CONFIG REQUIRED)
endif()
```

FoundationConfig.cmake is found but error "include could not find load file: @Foundation_EXPORTS_FILE@"

I'm pretty sure this is due to fact that Foundation file is in a different directory.  I only need clarification as to what @ Foundation_EXPORTS_FILE@ means.  I have been unable to find any reference to _EXPORTS_FILE.

Comment: what does this have to do with Visual Studio Code. It looks like a CMake problem and you don't have a CMake tag, And you mention `visual studio 2019` in the title, looks like unrelated

Comment: I corrected tag.

Comment: I corrected tag.

Answer (score -1):

Believe I found part of what I was lookin for here.

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/ExportInterface

The other half of the problem was found here -

[default search paths for CMake include() vs. find_package()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027646/default-search-paths-for-cmake-include-vs-find-package)

"include(@Foundation_EXPORTS_FILE@)"  Was in reference to the two config files, which are not in the same location, also include() searches for files in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH --- message("Path- ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")